# How to add data to a TrieMap[Long,List[Long]] in Scala

Tags: scala

i have this:

```
val vertexIdListPartitions: TrieMap[Long, List[Long]] = TrieMap()
```

i need to add `List(3)` at `vertexIdListPartitions(3)`.

I try to do this with:

```
vertexIdListPartitions(3)++List(3)
```

but it doesn't work.

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mutable collections have the `update()` method for this.

```
vertexIdListPartitions.update(3L, List(3))  //res0: Unit = ()
vertexIdListPartitions  //res1: TrieMap[Long,List[Long]] = TrieMap(3 -> List(3))
```

Comment: And if I need to understand if it contains it?
`if(vertexIdListPartitions(3).contains(List(3))) { return true}` is true?

Comment: Did you try it? Even if it worked (it doesn't) that would be a very poor way to test the contents of a `Map`. Try this: `vertexIdListPartitions.exists{case (k,v) => k == 3L && v == List(3L)}`